# PHP convert CSV to specific JSON distribution

Tags: php, json, csv

I have a PHP file that converts CSV to JSON, but I want the output JSON to have a different "hierarchy" that the one I'm getting right now (see below).

My CSV file looks kind of like this:

```
Icon Name, Responses, Performance  
03_v10_Assembly_point, 225, 38  
55_v10_Fire, 203, 87  
23_v10_Warning_volcano, 324, 79
```

And I want the outputted JSON to look like this:

```
{
    "03_v10_Assembly_point" {
            "Responses": "225",
            "Performance": "38"
    },
    "55_v10_Fire" {
            "Responses": "203",
            "Performance": "87"
    },
    "23_v10_Warning_volcano" {
            "Responses": "324",
            "Performance": "79"
    }
}
```

Or similar, the important thing is to have the first column as the "header" of the other parameters.

Is there a way to do that? :(

**UPDATE 12/22/18**

Although the question has already been answered, here's the original JSON output I had:

```
[
    {
        "Icon": "03_v10_Assembly_point",
        "Responses": "225",
        "Performance": "38",
        "id": 0
    },
    {
        "Icon": "55_v10_Fire",
        "Responses": "203",
        "Performance": "87",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "Icon": "23_v10_Warning_volcano",
        "Responses": "324",
        "Performance": "79",
        "id": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: Yes there are ways of doing that. What have you attempted? Please post your code.

Comment: You should also include what you're currently getting into the question itself, an not as an off-site link. When that link changes, this question will make less sense for future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read the csv file line by line. I escaped the first line because we don't need it in your case.

```
<?php   
$file = fopen('file.csv', 'r'); //read the csv file. Change file.csv to your current file
$i = 0; //initialize $i
$new_arr = array(); //initialize $new_arr
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) { //Read each line of the file
    if($i != 0){ //Check if we are on the first line or not
        $new_arr[$line[0]] = array("Responses" => $line[1], "Performance" => $line[2]); //Save info from csv into the new array
    }
    $i++; //Increment by one to escape only the first line
}
fclose($file); //Close file
echo json_encode($new_arr); //Encode result as json and make an echo
```

Output:

```
{  
   "03_v10_Assembly_point":{  
      "Responses":" 225",
      "Performance":" 38 "
   },
   "55_v10_Fire":{  
      "Responses":" 203",
      "Performance":" 87 "
   },
   "23_v10_Warning_volcano":{  
      "Responses":" 324",
      "Performance":" 79"
   }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfect!

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = [];

$data = array_slice(array_map('str_getcsv', file('file.csv')), 1); # read csv, skip header

foreach ($data as list($index, $responses, $performance))
{
    $result[$index] = ['Responses' => trim($responses), 'Performance' => trim($performance)];
}

$result = json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Warning !! This will only work if the csv doesn't have any values containing line breaks, commas or are surrounded by quotes

Maybe it is not best method to use, but it show how You can do this.

```
// Delete first line, and load file using file_get_contents to $csv var
$csv = '03_v10_Assembly_point, 225, 38' . PHP_EOL .
'55_v10_Fire, 203, 87' . PHP_EOL . 
'23_v10_Warning_volcano, 324, 79';

$csv_file = explode(PHP_EOL , $csv);
foreach($csv_file as $line) {
    $csv_array = explode("," , $line);

    $json_key = trim($csv_array[0]);

    $json[$json_key] = [
        'Responses' => trim($csv_array[1]),
        'Performance' => trim($csv_array[2])
    ];

}

print_r($json);

// now create json
$json = json_encode( $json );
```

and the results are

```
Array
(
    [03_v10_Assembly_point] => Array
        (
            [Responses] =>  225
            [Performance] =>  38
        )

    [55_v10_Fire] => Array
        (
            [Responses] =>  203
            [Performance] =>  87
        )

    [23_v10_Warning_volcano] => Array
        (
            [Responses] =>  324
            [Performance] =>  79
        )

)

{"03_v10_Assembly_point":{"Responses":" 225","Performance":" 38"},"55_v10_Fire":{"Responses":" 203","Performance":" 87"},"23_v10_Warning_volcano":{"Responses":" 324","Performance":" 79"}}
```

Comment: That's not a good way to read/parse CSV's in PHP. If there would be some column/value that contains a line break, it would mess your result up. You should use `fgetcsv()` instead.

Comment: Yes I agree, but if he needs to make it better, he should use some csv file parser class or function that uses @executable way.

Comment: If you agree, why are you posting this as an answer?

Comment: Becouse this is also answer to this question. His data is simple, so my method should work like a charm :-) I don't recommend to use it for more complex csv.

Comment: We don't know where that CSV comes from or if it will change tomorrow, so you should _always_ suggest best practice code. Knowingly suggesting bad practices are bad for everyone. Specially without any note/warnings about it in the answer.

Comment: On top of my comment I said about that. Csv files also u can save using libreoffice to specific format.

Comment: _"Maybe it is not best method to use"_ - is not the same as _"this will only work if the csv doesn't have any values containing line breaks, commas or are surrounded by quotes"_, which are valid CSV characters. Also, you need to trim the values before storing them: `" 225"` is a string with a leading space and is not the same as the value `"225"`

Comment: DV for using `explode()` even though PHP has built-in functions for properly dealing with CSV.